# Different certificate issuers on same site based on browser

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, account-security

When I try to access some web site on firefox I get this:

[image]

The cut out rectangle is COMPANY-NAME-ROOT-CA and that issuer (COMPANY-NAME-ROOT-CA) was also added as trusted on some peoples PC.

**But when I visit same site using chrome I don't get such warning and certificate issuer seems to be legitimate (e.g. Let's Encrypt Authority X3). **Does this mean I am safe to access this web site using chrome?****

I know we had some reservations company could have set up MITM kind of thing, but I am curious if I am safe with Chrome since we don't get above warning on chrome.

Comment: Are you certain that chrome shows correct certificate when your firefox shows this error,does this happen at the same time?

Comment: @VipulNair Yes I am sure this is issue for example on Chrome "DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
". Same site, yes.

Comment: Check proxy settings too, maybe one of the browsers connects to the site using a proxy

Comment: Or, possibly related to SNI.  Can you tell us the URL of the site?